# Excel, replace multiple

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to know if something like this is possible with Excel.

Each week we have reports that are received that need many corrections.  Right now, these are being done manually-leading to hours of work, since there are hundreds of corrections to be made.

The Client Name is the only common factor in Col B.  We want to be able to lookup the client name, but replace the information in Col A from a created list, for all of the client names that are on the list (and not one by one).

Col A : 12345  Col B: Client Name
Col A : 45678  Col B: Client Name

Col A needs to be replaced with "ABCDE" based on the lookup on the client name.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give us more information though like where the "created list" is saved.

But to answer your question, this is possible but you won't be able to do it in COL A, you might want to use a different column.

let's say you have data from Column A to Column F, use the next one which is Column G then do a Vlookup

assuming the "Created List" table is in a different sheet (Sheet2)
and has 2 columns (COL A = Company Name, COL B = ABCD)

All you have to do is do =VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet3!$A:$B,2,0)

- B2 is the Company name
- the $ sign makes sure the A and B columns in sheet 2 are selected permanently
- the 2 makes sure the data in the 2nd column will show, in this case, ABCD
- the 0 says always find the exact match

Comment: This looks like it will work perfectly-thank you!